# Get a piece of text from current url using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to get a piece of text from a link and store it in a variable. Let's say I have the following link:

```
categories/name/products
```

Could you please help me to get the 'Name' from the link considering that 'Categories' and 'Products' words never change.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/

Comment: What now? Current URL or link?

Comment: Sorry @connexo , I didn't notice the comment. Next time will pay more attention :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to get a zero based array out of your url string:

```js
var url = 'categories/name/products',
    arr = url.split('/');

console.log(arr[1]);
```

Comment: that would return the first word in a actual url. (for example: www.google.com/search/something/else it would return search instead of something)

Comment: The array you get out of `String.prototype.split()` is zero based

Comment: try `console.log(window.location.pathname.split('/')[1])` inside the developers console in this page, you will see it will pick questions instead of 41259089

Comment: Check that in my example I am calling `split` method on the string: `'categories/name/products'`..

Comment: That is because the url actually starts with a `/`, so `"/a/b/c".split("/")` results in `["", "a", "b", "c"]`.

Comment: correct, i just mentioned it because `window.location.pathname` is the most common way to get that actual piece of text

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. I will mark it as the correct answer once the option is available.

Comment: @EmilGurbanov it has been right in my answer for quite some time now.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the string would be one option:

```
url.split("/")[1]
```

Note: As mentiond by connexo, if you get the url

> by accessing window.location.pathname

the url starts with an `/` and the index has to be `2`in this solution.

Regular Expressions would be another way:

```
/categories\/(.+?)\/products/.exec(url)[1]
```

In this case the index has a different meaning (1st capture group) and stays 1.

Comment: 0 should be 1 here

Comment: 1 should be 2 here as getting the URL will be done by accessing window.location.pathname and that string will always start with `/`.

Comment: Right. Corrected it and provided regex solution as well.

Comment: @connexo My answer refers to the string given in the question. But thanks, your comment might help the OP.

Comment: That is because the url actually starts with a `/`, so `"/a/b/c".split("/")` results in `["", "a", "b", "c"]`

Answer (score 1):

```
// get the current url part after top level domain
var currentUrl = window.location.pathname; // will be "/categories/name/products"
// split the string at the /
// will give you [ "", "categories", "name", "products" ]
// Then access array element with index 2 (index on arrays is 0-based)
var extract = currentUrl.split("/")[2];
```